# std::bind and std::function overlap or complementary?

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, stl

I was looking at [this exemple here](http://thisthread.blogspot.be/2010/05/boostfunction-and-command-pattern.html), combining std::bind and std::function so as to create a command: really neat! The code for the command class goes like this:

```
class Command
{
 private:
   std::function<void ()> _f;

 public:
   command() {}
   command(std::function<void ()> f) : _f(f) {}

   template <typename T> void setFunction (T t) {_f = t ;}
   void execute()
    {
        if(!_f.empty())
            _f();
    }
};
```

Assuming I have a class `MyClass` containing a member function:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    void myMemberFn() {}
}
```

Then the calling code looks like:

```
MyClass myClass;

command(std::bind(&MyClass::myMemberFn, myClass));
```

Though I must admit I do not really understand why `std::function` is needed in addition to `std::bind`. It seems to me that bind already encapsulates the function call, so why is function needed in `Command`? Couldn't `Command`store a `std::bind` rather than a `std::function`?

I have been looking at documentation for both [std::bind](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) and [std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and did not get it...

Anyone has an idea of why `std::function`is needed?

**PS:** I am assuming std::bind ~= boost::bind and std::function ~= boost::function

Comment: `std::bind` is a *function* template that can be used to copy-initialize or assign to `std::function`, which is a *class* template.

Comment: `setFunction` would be better as a non-template `void setFunction(std::function<void()> t) {_f = std::move(t);}`. It's no more expensive than the template version, and possibly less so thanks to the `move`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to store the result of the `std::bind` expression somewhere. The return type of `std::bind` itself is unspecified by the standard, so you cannot create a named member variable of that type (you can use the C++11 `auto` to create such a local variable, though!)

Also, any function taking `std::function` can (due to `std::function` implicit conversions) accept all sorts of callable objects, not just `std::bind` results - you can pass it a regular function pointer, a lambda, a custom function object, whatever that can be invoked.

Comment: There are some template tricks which do allow you to store a type T where T is deduced to the return type of `std::bind`.

Comment: Besides, it's worth mentioning that `function` certainly has some runtime overhead.

Answer (score 1):

From the [bind](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) documnentation,

```
A function object of unspecified type T, for which std::is_bind_expression<T>::value == true, 
and which can be stored in std::function.
```

So

```
std::function<void ()> _f;
```

is needed to store the return value of

```
command(std::bind(&MyClass::myMemberFn, myClass));
```

so that this can be actually invoked later.